# Array and hashes declared using $ symbol in perl

Tags: perl, operators

I was studying arrow operator in perl when i came across this:

```
# Perl program to demonstrate the Arrow Operator

#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# reference to array
my $arr1 = [4,5,6];

# array inside array
my $arr2 = [4,5,[6,7]];

# reference to hash
my $has1 = {'a'=>1,'b'=>2};

# hash inside hash
my $has2 = {'a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>[1,2],'d'=>{'x'=>3,'y'=>4}};

# using arrow operator
print "$arr1->[0]\n";
print "$arr2->[1]\n";
print "$arr2->[2][0]\n";
print "$has2->{'a'}\n";
print $has2->{'d'}->{'x'},"\n";
print $has2->{'c'}->[0],"\n";
```

Here, arrays and hashes are declared using $ symbol, but the code runs perfectly fine with this. Also code incurred errors when i replaced the $ signs in the declaration with @ and % symbols. This code is from [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-operators-set-2/?ref=lbp).

I browsed the internet for explanation but found similar thing done on [Educative](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-arrow-operator-in-perl-534).

Comment: array*ref*s and hash*ref*s, not arrays and hashes. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut

Answer (score 2):

Both `[]` and `{}` returns a reference, and references are scalars.

```perl
my $a = [ ... ];
my $h = { ... };
```

is equivalent to

```perl
my @anon_a = ...;
my $a = \@anon_a;

my %anon_h = ...;
my $h = \%anon_h;
```

And that's why you have to use

```perl
$a->[0]    # Access an element of the array referenced by `$a`.
```

instead of

```perl
$a[0]      # Access an element of the array `@a`.
```